# Insert array values into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

The variables are being posted from a previous page through array values.
when I print_r($values) I get the whole value on this array including the numerical values of the array ex: array[0], array[1] ..etc.
Please can some tell me what I am doing wrong. the implode function was not used because the values are passed from a cart page though session variables.

First part of code below:

```
<?php
    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
        $total = 0;
        echo '<form method="post" action="process.php">';
        echo '<ul>';
        $cart_items = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
           $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
           $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Title,Description,Price FROM main_menu WHERE MenuID='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
           $obj = $results->fetch_object();

            echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
            echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="model/cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
            echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj->Price.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo '<h3>'.$obj->Title.' (Code :'.$product_code.')</h3> ';
            echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$obj->Description.'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
            $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->Title.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->Description.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
            $cart_items ++;

        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<span class="check-out-txt">';
        echo '<strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong>  ';
                echo '<input name=\'submit\' type="submit" value="Complete Order" style=\"width:150px;background:#333;color:#ffcc33;height:30px;\" />';
        echo '</span>';
        echo '</form>';

    }else{
        echo 'No items added';
    }

    ?>
```

Second part:

Comment: Cuurent code will (assumed the sql is proper) generate one record with `item_name` set, next new record with `price` set, next new record with `item_code` set etc. I assume you want to have one record with all of the fields set?

Comment: For last 12 minutes no reply and response ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$post` and the `table name` in the given function and  use mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid any possibility of the SQL Injection

**form.php**

```
<?php

 include ('func_curd.php') ;
 if($_POST['hiddenfieldinfo']=='ok')
    { 
        $r=insert_your_table_name($_POST); 
        if($r==true) 
            {  

                header('Location:'.get_full_url()); /* to redirect the form to the same page after successful submission*/          
            }
    } 
?>
```

**func_curd.php**

```
<?php        
function insert_your_table_name($post)
{        
 unset($post['hiddenfieldinfo']); 
   /* Here I am unsetting this value as it is hidden field 
in the form , which I am using as form submission check and 
is not in database column, apart form auto-increment in database 
that is id, you have to maek sure all the post value and column
 name matches with case-sensitivities  */
 $u = insert('your_table_name', $post);

                            $r=is_numeric($u)? true : false ;

                            return $r;

}


        function insert($table, $values){

                $query="INSERT INTO `$table` ";

                $column='(';

                $val=' (';

                $count=count($values);

                $mk=1;

                foreach ($values as $key=>$value)

                {

                    $value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);

                    if ($mk==$count)

                    {

                        $column .= '`'.$key.'`';

                        $val .= "'".$value."'";

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        $column .= '`'.$key.'`, ';

                        $val .= "'".$value."', ";

                    }

                    $mk++;

                }

                $column .=') ';

                $val .=')';

                $query=$query.$column.'VALUES'.$val;

                $Q=mysql_query($query);

                if(mysql_error())

                {

                    return print(mysql_error());

                }

                else

                {

                    $insert_id=mysql_insert_id();

                    return $insert_id;

                }

            }

        ?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I can not seem to capture the values and it is only inserting null values in the table. Do you have any advise on how i could fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: check that all the name in the forms are matching and no column field is missing or getting extra... If any extra value in $_POST['your_field'] .. unset that field before passing it into insert function ...

Comment: This is the page i am getting the info from code below:

Comment: I have pasted some code that may give you an indication of what i am doing wrong ? thank you

Comment: name="item_name['.$cart_items.'] .. Is this the name of column in db . as it depends upon the number of times the loop executes and is variable..

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<?php
require_once('config/connect.php');

$item_name  = strip_tags($_POST['item_name']);  
$item_code  = strip_tags($_POST['item_code']);
$item_desc  = strip_tags($_POST['item_desc']);
$item_qty  = strip_tags($_POST['qty']);
$price = strip_tags($_POST['price']);

 $fields = "item_name, item_code, item_desc, price,qty";

 $query = "INSERT INTO `x` SET ";
 $i = 0;
 foreach( $fields as $fieldname )
 {
        if ( $i > 0 )
            $query .= ", ";
        $val = strip_tags($_POST[$fieldname]);  
        $query .= "`" . $fieldname . "` = '" . $val . "'"

        $i++
 }

 $query_result = mysql_query($query);
 echo" Record saved";
 print_r ( $query );
?>
```

There are certain syntax errors in your code like not closed foreach etc. whihc I did skip.

As a recommendation: code like this is disclosing the database structure to everyone on the internet - form field names = database col names. This is generally a bad idea.
Better is a kind of mapping table:

```
 $fields = array (
      'myFormName' => 'mySqlName',
      ....


 foreach( $fields as $fieldname => $sqlame)
 {
        if ( $i > 0 )
            $query .= ", ";
        $val = strip_tags($_POST[$fieldname]); 
        $query .= "`" . $sqlname. "` = '" . $val . "'"
        ....
```

which also will make the form more independent from the underlying data structures.